# What's the meaning "did" and "through" in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

I came across this sentence "So did the Old Ball; it lay there sighing through its crack all day long,"

The context is that the Old ball broke and new ball was bought. And this Old Ball is anthropomorphic.

I couldn't understand the meaning "did" and "through" in this sentence. Does "through" mean "caused by"? What's the meaning "did" in this sentence?

Comment: More context or source would help. My guess is that if you imagine a ball with cracks on its surface, its inner self is sighing outward, now that it was old and broken. You can't know what *did* refers to, because we can't tell what *so* means without a contextual reference. For example, in "The big ball bounced, and so did the old ball.", I know what the old ball did (bounced). But just "so did the old ball" does not.

Comment: Does this "so" mean "it lay there sighing through its crack all day long"?

Comment: *so* is a continuation of a previous action. "You went to the store. So did I". (I also did what you described).

Answer (score 5):

Sentences don't ordinarily occur in a vacuum: **context** is usually critical to understanding.

*So* with auxiliary inversion in the following clause is usually employed with the sense "thus"; this is an anaphor, referring to an action mentioned immediately before the clause. It usually carries the additional sense "too, also". Here's your sentence in context:

> But a few days later they could hear a bouncing noise outside the shed; bump-bump it went against the wall, and the Wheelbarrow knew what that meant. So did the Old Ball; it lay there sighing through its crack all day long.

*So did the Old Ball* means that *The Old Ball, too, knew what that meant.*

*Sighed through its crack* is also explained in context. Just three short paragraphs earlier we read:

> “Look, there’s my ball!” she shouted, and hugged the Ball tightly. But it sagged and made a hissing noise because it had a split in its rubber tummy.

The *crack* is the *split* in the ball; as JavaLatte says, the author treats this as an "anthropomorphic mouth" through which the ball sighs.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I didn't write this context because they are so long but it seemed this context was necessary to answer this question.

Comment: @KinzleB But I didn't mention "personification"!

Answer (score 1):

**do so** is sometimes used in the in the sense **do this**. See the TO AVOID REPEATING section of [do](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do) or the first section of [this](http://www.englishgrammar.org/do-so-do-it-and-do-that/). The word order can be reversed, for example **so did I**.

If the preceding text is not relevant, this is an unusual usage because it precedes the repetition: it shows a poetic disregard for normal sentence structure. What it means is:

> the Old Ball did this; it lay there sighing through its crack all day long

I think that the crack is supposed to be its anthropomorphic mouth, so it is sighing through its mouth.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. I got it and does "this" in your sentence mean "it lay there sighing through its crack all day long"?

Comment: @Yuuichi Tam: Exactly.

Comment: Is there a sentence starting with 'Like' preceding this one?

Comment: No, I first think "did the Old bowl so" and what's meaning of transitive "do".

Comment: @StoneyB: you are right. It is indeed clear from the preceding sentence.